# C# Dictionary with Simultanous Reading/Writing functionalty

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, synchronization, locking

Is there a data structure or an algorithm to implement following functionalty?

> Data is being received continously into the application in multiple
>   threads and being written to a dictionary type structure.
>   If someone wants to read the dictionary while it is being written to, instead of
>   using locking, the values available right before value updation 
>   started will be provided.

Comment: Have a look at [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: "being written to a dictionary type structure **using lock** " - I'd promote removing this from the requirements. That's an implementation detail that only makes your solution set smaller. What they mean is probably it shall be thread safe. But to enforce locking on lock-free datastructures is somewhat counter-productive.

Comment: Those requirements look more like a college assignment

Comment: @ColinM I have phrashed the question in this way so as to ask the specific point without bothering anyone with the details of my code. I assure you, I am not a college student.

Comment: It's a reasonable start at a specification regardless of whether it is a college assignment or a work assignment. The problem with the question is that it shows zero effort  at researching the problem on their own.

Comment: @Fildor I am currently using simple dictionary with lock to read and write values. I was looking for a way to improve performance in the application by removing waiting of locks. Also, most of the operations are individual writes for each key(realtime) with bulk read every few seconds.

Comment: "bulk read" also means "bulk remove"?

Comment: @Fildor No need to remove.

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the [ConcurrentDictionary<,>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary provides the functionality of multiple reads simultanously but I want to be able to read the last available value when a thread is writing to the dictionary. I don't think that is possible with ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: @RameshVerma _" I don't think that is possible with ConcurrentDictionary_" What makes you think that?

Comment: @RameshVerma: "ConcurrentDictionary provides the functionality of multiple reads simultanously". Actually even a normal Dictionary provides the same functionality: "A Dictionary<TKey,TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2#thread-safety)

Comment: @LucaCremonesi As mentioned in my comment above, I want to read and write at same time, therefore "as long as the collection is not modified" part does not hold true for my case.

Comment: @RameshVerma: I know you want to concurrently read and write to the Dictionary. That's why the ConcurrentDictionary class suggested by James is most probably what you need. I was just pointing out that the ConcurrentDictionary class does much more than providing "the functionality of multiple reads simultaneously".